# Shell script for Android device as host and send cmd/message/broadcast to server

Tags: android, shell, adb, message, broadcast

For adb shell script, can I use the Android device as the host and send some message/cmd/broadcast to my linux server through the wifi connection? The simplest way is better. The message only includes 4bits text "0000","0001","0010", etc,. Because when the server receives this message/cmd/broadcast, server needs to change the chamber setting to the correct one. But I can only use shell script to perform this task on android device. Python script is not allowed. Is there any recommendation for this task?

Thanks.

Comment: You'd need to be connected  with the firewall set up correctly, and you'd need to know the IP of your server.  If that's done, you can send a message to it.  Doing it via shell script would require you to use some program on the phone to do the message sending-  what were you planning on using on the server to listen for it?  A web server?  ssh?  Something else?

Comment: If you have adb access to an Android device you can try to make use of the command-line tools like curl which is available on most Android devices. Via curl you should be able to create a network request to your Linux server. Note that on older Android phones apps have access to the shell command, so don't include any relevant passwords in the used command-line.

Comment: What's the service listening on the server? Are you sending binary data or just text? How's the network setup? Why do you need to send the message from the android device?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gabe Sechan give me a good idea to log the information on the web page. My Linux could monitor the web page and control the chamber in the laboratory.